# Share link on Instagram from my website in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, instagram, share

How can i share a link and photo with Instagram using rails..
Is it possible to post pictures to Instagram via the API

It would be helpful if there is some way to do this.

Comment: I am not getting your question? edit your question....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instagram API documentation is what you should be looking into, but it's mostly for retrieving data from Instagram. It will not allow you to post something, only Instagram Partners can do that.

More on that here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/content-publishing/

Comment: so, there is not any way to post on Instagram using application

Comment: There is other, not so direct ways to post something. You can use android/ios emulator to control the Instagram app, for example Bluestacks. Or you can control browser on pc with your app + selenium for example. But be careful, it's possible that these methods are against their policy.